# iOS - Change a ViewController with the keyboard "next" button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, keyboard

I've noticed it's possible to trigger actions and to move through text fields using the done/next/return key in the bottom right of the iOS keyboard. Would it be possible to maybe change a view or trigger a segue with that button?

For example, it would be cool to be able to type something into a UITextField, and then just tap "Next" to move onto the next viewController instead of having to use a separate button, or navigation item.

May be a stupid question, but something that I've been wondering if it was possible for a while.

Comment: Hi, "You can use `textFieldShouldReturn:` method to implement any custom behavior when the button(Return / Go/ Next .. what ever you have) is tapped.". All you need to do is set the `UITextField Delegate`, Implement the method `textFieldShouldReturn:` and do your custom work in there. HTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    //Next button was pressed
    //Push some viewcontroller here
    return YES;
}
```

make sure you set the delegate of the UITextField to self

Comment: Awesome, it works perfectly. So glad that I could do something like this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.  If it's a UITextField, you can implement textFieldShouldReturn:.  If it's a UITextView, you implement textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:, and look for \n in the replacement text.

In either case, you can then perform a segue, do a navigation or modal push, etc.